# Salesforce Apex Script to Move "Description" Field Content into a New Activity History Entry

Tags: salesforce

We're making an update to the way we use opportunities in our Salesforce account and I would like to automatically move all of the content from description fields into a new "Log a Call" entry in Activity History. Is there a quick way to do this, maybe using an apex script? We don't plan to use the description field anymore and want to hide it from the layout, but first we want to save that content in the activity history.

Answer (score 0):

Apex script would let you create at most 10K Tasks in one execution. If it's one-off data migration and you possibly have more Opps than that it's not worth the effort to build an Apex batch job for it.

I'd go with Data Loader. Export all Opps

```
SELECT Id, Description, CreatedDate FROM Opportunity WHERE Description != null
```

And then reload this file again as insert of Tasks. Map Opp Id to task's parentid etc, you get the idea. You might have to map some more fields (especially if your Tasks have validation rules), you will have to decide what to use as Task's date... But this sounds like easiest way to do it. Don't run it on all Opps initially, make a trial run in sandbox. Or pick a production opp but then filter it out from the full run's query.